# Траектория движения Android

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Пишу игру на SurfaceView и есть необходимость задать вращение обьекта относительно точки. Но вот проблема что делать если траектория движения овальная, какие для этого могут пригодиться формулы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим что у нас есть два объекта - **Earth** и **Moon**.

**Moon** вращается вокруг **Earth** по эллиптической траектории.

Нам нужно найти координаты объекта **Moon** в произвольной точке **z**.

Для этого можно воспользоваться уравнением в [параметрической форме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81#%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5):

```
x = a*cos(t) 
y = b*sin(t)
```

где:

- **a** - горизонтальное расстояние от **Earth** до **Moon**;
- **b** - вертикальное расстояние от **Earth** до **Moon**;
- **t** - угол, относительно горизонтальной оси.

предположим что угол **t** у нас равен 60°.

итого с учетом того что **a** = 3, **b** = 1 получаем:

```
x = 3*cos(60)
y = 1*sin(60)
```

т.е. координаты **Moon** в точке **z** = (1.5, 0.86)

[image: описание изображения]

PS: все совпадения с реальными объектами абсолютно случайны)